# Get dynamic zone type in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I have Strapi set up as a headless CMS and Gatsby on the frontend. In Strapi I have a "Single" type set up with a dynamic zone that the user can use to insert various components to it.

When querying directly from Strapi GraphQL, I can get the component type, like this:

```
{
  inicio {
    componentes {
      __typename
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "inicio": {
      "componentes": [
        {
          "__typename": "ComponentPaginasCitaBiblica"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "ComponentPaginasAlerta"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "ComponentPaginasTexto"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However in Gatsby, I get a different result:

```
query MyQuery {
  strapiInicio {
    componentes {
      __typename
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "data": {
    "strapiInicio": {
      "componentes": [
        {
          "__typename": "StrapiInicioComponentes"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "StrapiInicioComponentes"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "StrapiInicioComponentes"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

I need to select different fields depending on the component type and be able to display them correctly on the page, however, `__typename` is always set to `StrapiInicioComponentes`. Is there another way to get this from Gatsby?

The GraphiQL explorer doesn't show anything else there:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open bug](https://github.com/strapi/gatsby-source-strapi/issues/93) about this. [The fix](https://github.com/strapi/gatsby-source-strapi/pull/146) has been merged, however, at the time of writing, it has only been added to an alpha release, so use at your own risk.

To install the latest alpha version of `gatsby-source-strapi` with npm, execute:

```
npm i gatsby-source-strapi@alpha
```

This adds the component type to `strapi_component` in the GraphQL.

Or as an alternative, you could try [gatsby-source-rest-api](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-rest-api/), which exposes the component type under `_xcomponent`.